# Cached thumbs does not show up first time

Tags: php, caching, thumbnails, phpthumb

Im using phpThumb with mrPHPs cache script. When thumb is generated (first load), it does not show in browser - but all next loads are okay. This is really frustrating for clients, but it seems I can not find the solution.

If i check image with firebug it says it exists and shows nicely. What is the problem?

Here is a screenshot http://shrani.si/?1C/117/4K2CNJFQ/thumbproblem-copy.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It seems that upgrade to PHP 5.4.3 solved the problem.